# How to reduce first load page time of react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, react-redux

React project bundle size is too large although used all compression technique it takes too time to load first index page.First browser download bundle js and then load page.How to load index page first then other component bundle.
Following is webpack.js

```
  module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
  entry: {
    'main': [
      'bootstrap-sass!./src/theme/bootstrap.config.prod.js',
      'font-awesome-webpack!./src/theme/font-awesome.config.prod.js',
      './src/client.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    filename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: ''
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: [strip.loader('debug'), 'babel']},
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')},
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!less?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap=true&sourceMapContents=true') },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=2&sourceMap!autoprefixer?browsers=last 2 version!sass?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap=true&sourceMapContents=true') },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
      { test: webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin.regular_expression('images'), loader: 'url-loader?limit=10240' },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' }
    ]
  },
  progress: true,
  resolve: {
    modulesDirectories: [
      'src',
      'node_modules'
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
 plugins: [
    // css files from the extract-text-plugin loader
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]-[chunkhash].css', {allChunks: true}),

    // ignore dev config
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\.\/dev/, /\/config$/),

    // optimizations
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),

    webpackIsomorphicToolsPlugin
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Please prefer the dynamic [`import`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) function to split your code easily and without changing much. As a general guideline, dynamically import all of your top route components. When combined with [pre-loaded modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prefetching-preloading-modules), this will be a very effective tool for splitting your code fast and effectively.

When you do this, you can use any of the available load wrapper libraries like `react-loadable` to display a waiting component while your actual component is being imported.

An example (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting):

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';
import Loading from './Loading';

const LoadableComponent = Loadable({
  loader: () => import(
                  /* webpackPreload: true */ 
                  /* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ 
                  './Dashboard'
                ),
  loading: Loading,
})

export default class LoadableDashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <LoadableComponent />;
  }
}
```

In the above example, magic-comments are used to define the pre-load behavior and split chunk-name. Read more about these [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-).

> Use dynamic imports to split your non-react code as well, e.g. stores.

Answer (score 0):

## You can follow strategy of code splitting for effective load.

> The open source library react-loadable provides a React-friendly API for code splitting,

Here is a link for a blog related to that:-

https://hackernoon.com/effective-code-splitting-in-react-a-practical-guide-2195359d5d49

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used above url but chunk file is not getting created